# How to stop a running mysql query

Tags: java, mysql, applet-servlet

How do I stop a running mysql query programmatically?

The problem I'm facing is that a query is constructed using user supplied data, and may occasionally take a very long time to execute (large tables 15 - 30 million rows). I want to offer the user a cancel-option, but don't know how to stop the currently executing mysql-query.

The application is a Java applet-servlet: the user specify criteria in the applet which is passed to the servlet where a handler-class is created to handle the request. This handler-class is self-contained re connect - query - disconnect to mysql.

Given this scenario, how do I cancel a running mysql-query?

Comment: Do it carefully, if you're killing a query will crash your table

Comment: @slashmais can you help me with the code you have user to stop or kill the query using java-servlets, i also have same kind of issue

Comment: @dheerajkumar: I wrote the code for a client & do not have access to it anymore. IIRC I read through the answers and constructed a scheme that worked.

Comment: @slashmais yupp i also  have to do something else because this is causing issues

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
KILL <thread_to_be_killed>;
```

Refer to the documentation for additional details

[Show The Process List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-processlist.html)

[Kill A Running Thread](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html)

Comment: using KILL QUERY is slightly preferable to KILL for this case. That way the query is killed, but not the connection
ref# the comment in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787651/how-can-i-stop-a-running-mysql-query"

Answer (score 2):

A separate JDBC connection is required, which means you'll have to create a new database handler instance. Execute [SHOW PROCESSLIST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html) statement and then loop through the results and execute a [KILL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/kill.html) statement for each thread id found for the given user.

The only reliable way I can think to do this is every user would have to log in to the database under a different user name, then get all thread id's for that user and kill all their threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can issue MySQL specific commands through the standard libraries provided by MySQL and run [KILL QUERY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html). Possibly it's best listing the processes and figuring out which thread you need to kill first.

Depending on your application this might create a security issue though (since you need to give more privileges to the connecting application user).