# How can I stop a running MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, kill, processlist

I connect to `mysql` from my Linux shell. Every now and then I run a `SELECT` query that is too big. It prints and prints and I already know this is not what I meant. I would like to stop the query.

Hitting `Ctrl+C` (a couple of times) kills `mysql` completely and takes me back to shell, so I have to reconnect.

Is it possible to stop a query without killing `mysql` itself?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that MySQL 5.7 supports a server-side SELECT statement timeout.  More information on this here: http://mysqlserverteam.com/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/

Comment: The article mentioned by @MorganTocker has been moved to https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/

Answer (score 544, accepted):

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+------+-----------+-----+---------+------+---------------------+------------------------------+----------+
| Id | User | Host      | db  | Command | Time | State               | Info                         | Progress |
+----+------+-----------+-----+---------+------+---------------------+------------------------------+----------+
| 14 | usr1 | localhost | db1 | Query   |    0 | starting            | show processlist             |    0.000 |
| 16 | usr1 | localhost | db1 | Query   |   94 | Creating sort index | SELECT  `tbl1`.* FROM `tbl1` |    0.000 |
+----+------+-----------+-----+---------+------+---------------------+------------------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

mysql> kill 16;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.004 sec)

mysql> show processlist;
+----+------+-----------+-----+---------+------+----------+------------------+----------+
| Id | User | Host      | db  | Command | Time | State    | Info             | Progress |
+----+------+-----------+-----+---------+------+----------+------------------+----------+
| 14 | usr1 | localhost | db1 | Query   |    0 | starting | show processlist |    0.000 |
+----+------+-----------+-----+---------+------+----------+------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: but `mysql` is printing... I can't see the prompt

Comment: I agree with this basic approach, but I think using `KILL QUERY` is slightly preferable to `KILL` for this case. That way the query is killed, but not the connection.

Comment: a useful tip if your process list is scrolling past your buffer is to set the pager.  Just enter '\P more' at the prompt.  See more on this tip here http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/03/28/how-to-work-with-a-long-process-list-in-mysql/

Comment: @Zilverdistel How do you do it in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: This didn't work for all queries. They said "sending data" Instead, I used kill query <id number no quotes>;

Comment: How do you do this WHILE your console is spewing out information?

Comment: You don't show mysql command against the `kill`. It's worthy noting that the the process numbers are not OS, and `kill` applies only to MySQL, and OS `kill`:  `mysql> kill <ID>;` or `$mysql -uusername -p  -hhostname -e 'kill <ID>'`

Comment: I get "ERROR 1094 (HY000): Unknown thread id: XXX" with XXX being the id from process list.

Comment: If using MySQL on AWS RDS, you won't have permission to run `KILL`, but you can run: `CALL mysql.rds_kill(12345)`

Answer (score 81):

Just to add

`KILL QUERY **Id**`
where Id is connection id from `show processlist`

is more preferable if you are do not want to kill the connection usually when running from some application.

For more details you can read mysql doc [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/kill.html)

Comment: A question I had related to this, does the connection just respawn, or does killing connections eventually result in the pool size being too small for the application to run?

Answer (score 51):

**Connect to mysql**

```
mysql -uusername -p  -hhostname
```

**show full processlist:**

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id      | User   | Host              | db      | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 9255451 | logreg | dmin001.ops:37651 | logdata | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```

**Kill the specific query. Here id=9255451**

```
mysql> kill 9255451;
```

**If you get permission denied, try this SQL:**

```
CALL mysql.rds_kill(9255451)
```

Comment: Note: That last query is required if using AWS RDS instance.

Answer (score 15):

Use `mysqladmin` to kill the runaway query:

Run the following commands:

```
mysqladmin -uusername -ppassword pr
```

Then note down the process id.

```
mysqladmin -uusername -ppassword kill pid
```

The runaway query should no longer be consuming resources.

Answer (score 9):

If you have `mysqladmin` available, you may get the list of queries with:

```
> mysqladmin -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD pr

+-----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+--------------+------------------+
| Id  | User | Host            | db     | Command | Time | State        | Info             |
+-----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+--------------+------------------+
| 137 | beet | localhost:53535 | people | Query   | 292  | Sending data | DELETE FROM      |
| 145 | root | localhost:55745 |        | Query   | 0    |              | show processlist |
+-----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+--------------+------------------+
```

Then you may stop the mysql process that is hosting the long running query:

```
> mysqladmin -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD kill 137
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to run following command to kill the process.
Find out the id of the process which you wanted to kill by

```
> show processlist;
```

Take the value from id column and fire below command

```
kill query <processId>;
```

Query parameter specifies that we need to kill query command process.

The syntax for kill process as follows

> KILL [CONNECTION | QUERY] processlist_id

Please [refer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/kill.html) this link for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The author of this question mentions that it’s usually only after
MySQL prints its output that he realises that the wrong query was executed.
As noted, in this case, `Ctrl-C` doesn’t help. However, I’ve noticed that it
*will abort the current query* – if you catch it **before** any output is
printed. For example:

```
mysql> select * from jos_users, jos_comprofiler;
```

MySQL gets busy generating the Cartesian Product of the above two tables and
you soon notice that MySQL hasn't printed any output to screen (the process
state is *Sending data*) so you type `Ctrl-C`:

```
Ctrl-C -- sending "KILL QUERY 113240" to server ...
Ctrl-C -- query aborted.
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
```

`Ctrl-C` can similarly be used to stop an `UPDATE` query.