# started an infinite procedure in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, system-administration

I call a procedure that includes an infinite loop in `phpmyadmin`:

```
WHILE i < 10 DO
  INSERT INTO ...
END WHILE;
```

Then I can't get into `phpmyadmin` anymore. It just shows 500 error. Is it possible to resolve it without `root` permission?

Comment: Could you reboot the server? If its shared hosting justa call them and ask for a reboot/fix. Also, its mysql that is in a loop. Not phpmyadmin.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787651/how-can-i-stop-a-running-mysql-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you reboot the server? 
If its shared hosting just call them and ask for a reboot/fix. Also, its mysql that is in a loop. Not phpmyadmin.

Without ssh access and root powers you are pretty much stuck.

On shared hosting its possible eventually the process will be killed/server rebooted because it is probably eating up ressources.