# MySQL table hangs for update operation in one row

Tags: mysql, innodb

I had a stored procedure like following:

```
START TRANSACTION;
//Do a insert

//Do a select
COMMIT;
```

During the insert there was an error (I tried to insert with an existing primary key). Now, I can not update the row with the same primary key. MySQL Workbench hangs. I think I have to kill the process that tried and failed to insert.

Any idea how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop a running MySQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787651/how-can-i-stop-a-running-mysql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

to find the thread ID, then:

```
KILL id;
```