# how to kill process/Query with java

Tags: java, servlets, mysql-5.5

I am trying to kill the current process/query which is running from long and taking long time to execute

- I want to do it with java servlets
- I have a query and i ran it on my system but sometimes it is taking too much of time to get executed
- What i am trying to do is to kill that query which is taking long time
- I have google it a lot and found some help like with `show processlist` command in MySQL i can list up all the process which are currently in my system
- like this it populates in my razor Sql [image: click here to see process list]
- as you all can see in the image the process which is running has `stae=Sending data` so i want to kill that process with id where state=Sending data
- as simply in my SQL command i can write `kill id` it will kill the process whose id i give
- But i want to do this programmatically  with java servlet code
- I don't know how to do that,i am stuck here for so long

Below is my servlet do-Get and do-Post

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    doGet(request, response);
}
```

I just want to know how can i do it with with java code,please guide me anykind of help will be appreciated

[This is the link i have found but not getting idea how to achieve that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/kill.html)

Comment: You should consider improving your query performance, instead of killing the process.

Comment: no i can't ,i want to kill anyhow

Comment: You could set the max query timeout. If MySQL, starting from 5.7.8 there is a max_execution_time setting (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time).

Comment: @Chinmayjain i am using MySQL 5.5, and i can't  set max time out because, it is going to happen on the basis of user selection,when user clicks on UI(client-side) then i have to kill the query having state as Sending data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a running mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065396/how-to-stop-a-running-mysql-query)

Comment: @KevinO yup i already visited here,but there is no code like how can i write this in java servlet

Comment: I don't have a running mysql at the moment, but have you tried executing `show processlist;` in another connection? What does it return when there are running queries? One of the answers at that link certainly suggests that you will get the results.

Comment: @KevinO yup sir i have tried  `show processlist` it shows up me the full list of process  as i have posted a image also,then with `kill id` i can kill it, but issue is i want to do this with java code how can i do that there

Comment: I don't think you followed the point. You can -- in java -- using a `statement` execute a query `show processlist` and (probably) get back the results, at least according to the suggestions from the link.

Comment: @KevinO i am totally confused,i have visited that link but didn't understood how to do that,can you please help me with code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190080/discussion-between-kevino-and-dheeraj-kumar).